# typo3: social icons in fluid template with typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.6.x

I'll start with the snippets I'm trying to make work ...

I define the social accounts in constants.ts:

```
myExtension.configuration {

    socials {
        # cat=myExtension/socials/05; type=string; label=Facebook account:
        facebook = facebook.com/
        # cat=myExtension/socials/10; type=string; label=Twitter account:
        twitter = twitter.com/
        # cat=myExtension/socials/15; type=string; label=Google Plus account:
        googlePlus = plus.google.com/
        # cat=myExtension/socials/20; type=string; label=Youtube account:
        youtube = youtube.com/
    }
}
```

I declare the variable in page.ts

```
page = PAGE
page {
    # Page Main template
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        file = EXT:myExtension/Resources/Private/Templates/Main.html
        variables {    
            socials = TEXT
            socials.value = {$myExtension.configuration.socials}
        }
    }
}
```

then I try to use it in a template:

```
<f:render section="socials" />


<f:section name="socials">
  <ul class="list-inline hidden-print">
    <f:for each="{socials}" as="social" key="icon">
      <li>
        <a href="{social}">
          <i class="fa fa-{icon} fa-fw">
        </a>
      </li>
    </f:for>
  </ul>
</f:section>
```

I'm not yet that good with typo3 so it might be very simple, or the question very stupid ... I did not even figure out how to debug properly (so that I could first of all figure out how to be sure of the variable array 'socials')...

Comment: Looks good for the most part. The only problem is, if I'm not mistaken, that you can't propagate a whole array from constants to setup. Try to define all four services in the setup, and read the urls from the constants one by one.

Comment: I think you are right, I'm one step further ... thxs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to grab your constants one by one (as suggested by j4k3) - or skip that part altogether and directly define the value like this:

```
page = PAGE
page {
    # Page Main template
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        file = EXT:myExtension/Resources/Private/Templates/Main.html
        variables {    
            facebook = TEXT
            facebook.value = facebook.com/
            twitter = TEXT
            twitter.value = twitter.com/
            googlePlus = TEXT
            googlePlus.value = plus.google.com/
            youtube = TEXT
            youtube.value = youtube.com/
        }
    }
}
```

Then, to avoid duplicate code you can access the values by first mapping them on the fly and then iterating like this:

```
<f:alias map="{socials: {facebook: facebook, twitter: twitter, googlePlus: googlePlus, youtube: youtube}}">
  <f:render section="socials" arguments="{socials: socials}"/>
</f:alias>



<f:section name="socials">
  <ul class="list-inline hidden-print">
    <f:for each="{socials}" as="social" key="icon">
      <li>
        <a href="{social}">
          <i class="fa fa-{icon} fa-fw">
        </a>
      </li>
    </f:for>
  </ul>
</f:section>
```

Comment: thanks for your time, i'm a step further but there is anyhow something not working... i used a viewhelper to form the link now, and I declared the variables separately...
  'code' facebook = TEXT
   facebook.value = {$ionizer.configuration.socials.facebook} but the variable {social} doesn't pass on the uri ...

Comment: thanks for your time, i'm a step further but there is anyhow something not working... i used a viewhelper to form the link now, and I declared the variables separately...
  ` facebook = TEXT
    facebook.value = {$ionizer.configuration.socials.facebook}` but the variable {social} doesn't pass on the uri ...

Comment: ps: when I use {facebook} in the fluid template, I do get the uri defined in the constant ... just for your info ...

Comment: What do you get if you print out the socials array with <f:debug>{socials}</f:debug> inside the alias ViewHelper?

Comment: it is in a fluid template ... array(5 items)
   facebook => NULL
   twitter => NULL
   google-plus => NULL
   youtube-play => NULL
   stack-overflow => NULL

Comment: if I display it all directly, rather the reffering to a section and placing it in a section it works ... trouble is that I need to place it within various if then statements, its not clean coding that way ...

Comment: thx for the attention, does that work for you ? Itested using the variables outside of the section and that works ... inside the section the variables remain null

Comment: You need to map the array first and then pass it to the partial. See my updated answer. Sorry, I missed it before.

Comment: thank you !! do not apologise, you where very helpfull